# Throwing Errors When User Try's To Modify

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set up a users group permission role system where user can have or have not access to controllers and or modify them.

**Problem:** if I leave all my permission modify array unchecked for a particular user group. And if that user group tried to modify the controller It throws two errors. When modify permissions are unchecked.

**How can I make it so that it will work even if permissions are unchecked. And if user that has that user group try's to modify it. It will not throw these two errors.**

**Error One**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: modify
Filename: libraries/User.php
Line Number: 206
```

**Error Two**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
Filename: libraries/User.php
Line Number: 206
```

**User Library Function**

```
public function hasPermissionModify() {
      $user_id = $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id');
      $segment = $this->CI->uri->segment_array();                
      $permission = isset($segment[2]) ? $segment[2] : '';  

      $ignore = array(
         'blank',
         'error',
         'register',
         'dashboard',
         'column_left',
         'menu',
         'startup',
         'login',
         'logout',
         'forgotten',
         'reset',
         'not_found',
         'permission',
         'footer',
         'header'
      );

      if (isset($permission) && $permission && $user_id) { 
         if (in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
         return true;
      }

         $user_group_info = $this->CI->users_model->getUser($user_id);

         if (!empty($user_group_info)) {                

            $user_group_data = $this->CI->users_group_model->getUserGroup($user_group_info['user_group_id']);
         // Error Here
         if (!in_array($permission ,$user_group_data['permission']['modify'] )) {

            return false;

         } else {

            return true;

         }

         } else {

            return false;

         }  

      } else {

         return true;

      }

   }
```

Comment: Each user has there own user group id. In my user group I have a access and modify function. If the controller in the modify is unchecked in that user group he will not be able to update it. But throws the two errors on post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what `$this->CI->users_group_model->getUserGroup()` does - however you should check the index in case if does not exist, before doing an `in_array`and further examine the variable `$user_group_data` to see how it looks and go through getUserGroup function to see what it returns. See modifications to the function below:

```
public function hasPermissionModify() 
{
    $user_id = $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id');
    $segment = $this->CI->uri->segment_array();                
    $permission = isset($segment[2]) ? $segment[2] : '';  

    $ignore = array(
        'blank',
        'error',
        'register',
        'dashboard',
        'column_left',
        'menu',
        'startup',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'forgotten',
        'reset',
        'not_found',
        'permission',
        'footer',
        'header'
    );

    if (isset($permission) && $permission && $user_id) 
    { 
        if (in_array($permission, $ignore)) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        $user_group_info = $this->CI->users_model->getUser($user_id);

        if(!empty($user_group_info)) 
        {                

            $user_group_data = $this->CI->users_group_model->getUserGroup($user_group_info['user_group_id']);
            // Error Here

            //$user_group_data does not have an index called modify. 
            //Examine it here and check getUserGroup function to see what is wrong
            echo "value of user_group_data:<pre>".print_r($user_group_data,true)."</pre>";

            //in any case if that index is not there return false
            if((!array_key_exists('permission',$user_group_data)) ||
            (!array_key_exists('modify',$user_group_data['permission']))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!in_array($permission ,$user_group_data['permission']['modify'] )) 
            {
                return false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }  
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: An explanation would be beneficial.

Comment: errpr here  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-project\application\libraries\User.php on line 219(!array_key_exists('modify'),$user_group_data['permission']))

Comment: check now - there was an additional bracket

Comment: @raidenace The CI In the library is a get instance. I only took the function that was causing problem. I saw that i fixed it my self no errors showing now. +1 from me as well great

Comment: @raidenace Also if wanted to add second array key like access so can use all in one is that possible?

Comment: @acoderslife - not sure I understood you properly - if you want to add a new array key like `$user_group_data['permission']['access']` you can use the same syntax/steps as you are doing with `$user_group_data['permission']['modify']`